# How to send signal to a child process created via fork and execl?

Tags: process, c, signals, exec, fork

Assume I have a program `foo` that simply prints forever but is stopped before then,

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP);
    while(1) {
        printf("foo\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And then I have a program `bar` that forks and runs `foo`:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        execl("foo", "foo", NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I want `bar` to be able to send SIGCONT to `foo` so it can go on its printing duties, and then later send SIGSTOP again, and even later send SIGCONT again, and so on.

I couldn't figure out how to do that. Any help?

EDIT: I figured out my problem. Apparently, the `foo` program isn't ready to accept signals immediately when it runs. When I did

```
sleep(5);
int rc = kill(pid, SIGCONT);
```

it worked.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to (1) show what you tried, (2) explain exactly what happened when you tried it, and (3) remove the edit. Then (4) post an answer explaining the solution.  P.S. The situation might not be that “the `foo` program isn't ready to accept signals immediately when it runs”; it might be that you’re sending the SIGCONT signal before the `foo` process has stopped itself. Sending a continue signal to a process that’s running (i.e., that is not stopped) is a no-op (i.e., it is not queued). You could verify this experimentally by adding a `sleep(6)` to the beginning to `foo.c`.

Comment: oh. you're probably right.

Comment: when the PID is > 0, it is running in the parent so can then send a signal to the specific 'pid'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == 0)
{
    execl("foo", "foo", NULL);
}
int rc = kill(pid, 18);
return 0;
```

Comment: Is that supposed to make `foo` continue and do the printing? `foo` just stays hanging for me

Comment: −1 for replacing a symbolic constant with a literal constant — especially because SIGCONT is not [one of the ones whose value is universal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/317492/80216#317496) (see [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)).

Comment: @G-Man I was not happy with that either but I am not familiar with C, did not have the header file available, was not sure how exactly this must be done (`CONT` / `SIGCONT`) and `man 2 kill` which I looked at does not contain an example which would have made it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest: don't forget to handle errors codes from system calls! Work without handling of error codes is worse style! This two actions you can do in one program. In this case it's will be more effective:

```
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int rc = 0;

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) /* child */
    {
        kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP);
        if (rc == -1) {
                  perror("Something wrong while kill() in child");
        }
        while (1) {
                  printf("foo\n");
        }
    } else if (pid > 0) { /* father */
        rc = kill(pid, SIGCONT);
        if (rc == -1) {
                  perror("Something wrong while kill() in parent");
        }
    } else if (pid < 0) {
        perror("Something wrong while fork()");

        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you’re trying to present an example of good coding style, why are you using a literal constant instead of the symbolic constant SIGCONT  —  especially when [its value is not universal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/317492/80216#317496) (see [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html))?

Comment: @G-Man I know it. I replace it. I've just copy-paste this block from previous answer and forget to replace it.